# numericInput to data frame in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Sorry if this question has been asked before, but I haven't quite found exactly what I was looking for by searching around.

I'm working on a small app to bring in scores from a debate activity and have those scores plotted in a scatterplot. I've figured out how to actually *make* the plot, but getting the data into it is a separate story.
I have all of my inputs as a numericInput with a unique input ID, but I haven't had any luck putting that data into its own frame.

I tried making a few different sets and then compiling all of those into one frame (using `name1<-c(x, y z)`, `name2<-c(a,b,c)`... and then `frame<-as.matrix(c(name1,name2....))` but it tells me that I'm attempting to do something that requires a reactive context.

If anyone knows how I could make my numericInputs drop into a dataframe, that would be lovely.

EDIT: I *think* I'm looking to make a reactive data table, but I'm not entirely sure. Again, any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the description of your problem, which is not that clear and do not show exactly what you need, this is what I recomment:

An app which takes 6 numerics inputs, combine all in a data frame with two columns and create a scatter plot with that data.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# 1 - The UI with a sidebar layuot
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    # A well panell to separate the values
    # for the X axis
    sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(
      wellPanel(
      h3("X axis"),
      numericInput('numb1', 'A', value = 1),
      numericInput('numb2', 'B', value = 2),
      numericInput('numb3', 'C', value = 3)
    ),
    # A well panell to separate the values
    # for the Y axis
    wellPanel(
      h3("Y axis"),
      numericInput('numb4', 'A', value = 1),
      numericInput('numb5', 'B', value = 2),
      numericInput('numb6', 'C', value = 3)
    )),
    
    # Main panel with the plot
    mainPanel = mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
  
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Here You create a reactive objece with all the values
  data <- reactive({
    data.frame(
      a = c(input$numb1, input$numb2, input$numb3),
      b = c(input$numb4, input$numb5, input$numb6)
    )
  })
  
  # plot output
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
     data() %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = a, y = b)) +
      geom_point()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Let me know if this is it

Comment: YES! That was exactly it! Thanks for your help, this had been driving me up a wall all day.